# Can't call a Subflow from a record triggered flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, after, subflow

I have created a sub flow with inputs and outputs but the subflow icon is not available in the Elements menu. The flow fires after a record is saved, so my understanding is it should be able to fire subflows (unlike the before save fire). It is available if I create an Auto launched flow but that's not what I want. I also don't want to fire this from a process, as the sub flow needs to fire in a loop.

Does anyone know of any other reason subflows would not be available, or is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Winter '22 release will support subflow elements in record-triggered flows. See the Winter '22 release notes here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_subflows_record_triggered.htm&type=5&release=234.

Answer (score 2):

There is a clear indication [in the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_considerations_trigger_record.htm&type=5) what kind of core action are available in record trigged flow. Unfortunately, subflow element is not supported

Comment: The documentation says that is for before-save updates, whereas this is after-save

Comment: @BiscuitBulldozer You are right. There is no documentation yet for after-save updates. The only thing I was able to find is in [Architect Guide](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/highlight-architects-guide-building-record-triggered-automation-elly) which says: "Note: Flow triggers cannot invoke subflows as of Summer ’20, but it’s on the roadmap." I guess this applies for both type of trigger flows